# Big time difference in parsing two similar html files

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have two search results from a web-service saved as html that i have to parse with BeautifulSoup in order to extract some data. I noticed that one of them takes approx. 35 times longer than the other.

Someone has an explanation for this / an idea what i can do in order to improve the performance of the slower html file?

Setup:

```
Python 2.7.13
Jupyter Notebook 4.3.1
beautifulsoup4 (4.5.3)
lxml (3.8.0)
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "path to the files"
file_1 = "slow.html"
file_2 = "fast.html"

with open(path+file_1) as rfile_1:
    html_1 = rfile_1.read()
with open(path+file_2) as rfile_2:
    html_2 = rfile_2.read()

%timeit soup = BeautifulSoup(html_1, 'lxml')
>> 1 loop, best of 3: 4.67 s per loop
%timeit soup = BeautifulSoup(html_2, 'lxml')
>> 10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop
```

- [fast html file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B382p1NffKMmRl9ZTjd0YnUxaFU)
- [slow html file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B382p1NffKMmNWxxdHhPTTBiNUE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I timed BeautifulSoup on your two HTML files the results were the reverse of yours. 'fast' took roughly twice as long as 'slow'. I have no idea why this should be.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("import bs4;HTML = open('slow.html').read();bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')", number=1000)
83.10731378142236
>>> timeit.timeit("import bs4;HTML = open('fast.html').read();bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')", number=1000)
147.65896100030727
```

If parsing time is important then I would suggest the use of scrapy. For each of your files it delivered a result in about one-quarter of the time.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("from scrapy.selector import Selector;HTML = open('slow.html').read();Selector(text=HTML)", number=1000)
21.85675587779292
>>> timeit.timeit("from scrapy.selector import Selector;HTML = open('fast.html').read();Selector(text=HTML)", number=1000)
39.938533099930055
```

Comment: slow.html is about half the size of fast.html, so your results make sense. Since you don't get the same results in terms of 35x longer i can assume that there is an issue with my python/packages installation?
Get the same results than you when using scrapy - thanks for the tip

Comment: The short answer to that is, I don't know. By the time you have Python, Jupyter and all this stuff going, who can say? Getting meaningful timings is a headache in the first place.